# ColdFusion 10 ORM. How to customize EntityLoad return with 2 many-to-many tables?

Tags: mysql, orm, coldfusion, hql

I have 3 tables

**Users**

- users_pk
- userName

**Users_Settings**

- users_settings_pk
- users_fk
- settings_fk
- value

**Settings**

- settings_pk
- settingName
- valueList

**Users** has a *one-to-many* relationship to **Users_Settings**
**Settings** has a *one-to-many* relationship to **Users_Settings**

**Users_Settings** has a *many-to-one* relationship to **Users**
**Users_Settings** has a *many-to-one* relationship to **Settings**

How would I use EntityLoad to get all the settings.name and associated users_settings.value for a specific user?

My current solution is to make a custom query or use cfquery but was wondering if there is a way using coldfusion ORM.

Comment: It might be easier to simply set settings as a many-to-many on users, and users as a many-to-many on settings, each using Users_Settings as a 'link table'

Comment: The only downside to that is that I won't be able to have the Users_Settings.value column.

Comment: Missed that property initially. Best bet would be to use HQL and `ORMExecuteQuery()`, `entityLoad()` won't be work for that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these components and their relationships are similar to yours (just minimal code here, leaving off inits(), inverse etc, )...

**User.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="users"{
    property name="users_pk" fieldType="id" generator="native";
    property name="name" column="userName";
    property name="settings" fieldType="one-to-many" cfc="UserSetting" fkColumn="users_fk";
}
```

**Setting.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="settings"{
    property name="settings_pk" fieldType="id" generator="native";
    property name="name" column="settingName";
    property name="userSettings" fieldType=s"one-to-many" cfc="UserSetting" fkColumn="settings_fk";
}
```

**UserSetting.cfc**

```
component persistent="true" table="users_settings"{
    property name="users_settings_pk" fieldType="id" generator="native";
    property name="value";
    property name="user" fieldType="many-to-one" cfc="User" fkColumn="users_fk";
    property name="setting" fieldType="many-to-one" cfc="Setting" fkColumn="settings_fk";
}
```

...you should be able to load a user and output their settings as follows:

**ShowUserSettings.cfm**

```
<cfset user =   EntityLoadByPK( "User",1 )>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User settings</title>
</head>
<body>
    <cfoutput>
        <h2>User #user.getName()#</h2>
        <dl>
            <cfloop array="#user.getSettings()#" index="userSetting">
                <dt>Setting: #userSetting.getSetting().getName()#</dt>
                <dd>Value: #userSetting.getValue()#</dd>
            </cfloop>
        </dl>
    </cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, another question I had is: if given a users PK and a settings PK, what would be the best and most efficient way to find the corresponding users_settings record to update? EX in SQL would be SELECT * FROM users_settings where user_fk = 1 and setting_fk = 1.